# Is it possible to calculate a sine of timeline's `Time`variable in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, trigonometry

I need a ping-pong movement along X axis for 3D cube. So I applied trigonometric `sine` function to `time` variable for `x` parameter. But there's no ping-pong motion, only scalar one.

Any help appreciated!

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    .......

    //CFTimeInterval derived by calling `mach_absolute_time()` and converting the result to seconds.
    let t = CACurrentMediaTime()

    animation.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector3: SCNVector3(x: CGFloat(sin(t)*5), 
                                                       y: CGFloat(0), 
                                                       z: CGFloat(0)))

    animation.duration = 60
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT    
    cube.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to calculate a sine of timeline's time in SceneKit. For this I need to create an extension for `SCNAction` (in Swift 4.1):

```
let pi = CGFloat(Double.pi)

extension SCNAction {

    static func oscillation(amplitude a: CGFloat, 
                           timePeriod t: CGFloat) -> SCNAction {

        let action = SCNAction.customAction(duration: Double(t)) { node, currentTime in
            let offset = a * sin(2 * pi * currentTime / t)
            node.position.x = offset
        }
        return action
    }
}

class GameViewController: NSViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

    let box = SCNNode()
    // ..................

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ..................
        box.geometry = SCNBox()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box)

        let oscillate = SCNAction.oscillation(amplitude: 4, timePeriod: 1)
        box.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(oscillate))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the following code is that it is executed when the animation is *instantiated*, not when the animation is *evaluated*. That is the value `sin(t)` will never change over time. It's evaluated once and the result will be the final value for the linear interpolation.

```
let t = CACurrentMediaTime()
animation.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector3: SCNVector3(x: CGFloat(sin(t)*5), 
                                                   y: CGFloat(0), 
                                                   z: CGFloat(0)))
```

---

Instead, the `CAAnimation` class exposes the [`timingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation/1412456-timingfunction) property which is likely what you want.

Comment: Eventually pacing could achieve the same effect. Have a look at `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut` : «Ease-in-ease-out pacing, which causes an animation to begin slowly, accelerate through the middle of its duration, and then slow again before completing.»

Comment: `timingFunction` is about interpolation of a curve (predefined curve's profiles like `kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear` or `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut`). It's not about `sine wave`, its `frequency`, positive/negative parts, `offset` and `amplitude`.